# Angular - downloading a file doesn't work in Edge

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, download, microsoft-edge

I have an Angular 7 app that calls an ASP.NET Web API function which returns data in the form of an `.xlsx` Excel file back to Angular.

Using this code, I then create an invisible `<a>` tag and click it to start the download of that binary file down to the client:

```
this.reportService.createReport(this.reportOption,
    (data) => {
        const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' });

        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(a);

        a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();

        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        a.remove();
    },
    (error: string) => {
        this.messsageService.showError(error);
    });
```

This code works flawlessly in Firefox and Chrome - no troubles at all.

But in MS Edge, for some reason, the download isn't started. I don't see any errors in the Javascript console, there it just says "Download successfully started" - but there's no prompt to the user where to save the file - and the file also isn't silently downloaded into the configured default download directory.

Any ideas? Has anyone else seen this with Edge, and found a solution for this?

Comment: can you give more details from network console if get request actually occurs and is equal to  the chrome request so the same response from ASP.NET occurs?

Comment: @Lucho: the console output seems identical to the one in Chrome - no errors, no warnings, no hints of any trouble - the file just isn't returned to the client ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the IE/Microsoft Edge browser, you could use the msSaveOrOpenBlob method to download the file. Please try to modify your code as below:

```
//change to your format.
var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
//output file name
var fileName = "test.pdf";

//detect whether the browser is IE/Edge or another browser
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
  //To IE or Edge browser, using msSaveorOpenBlob method to download file.
  window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
} else {
    //To another browser, create a tag to downlad file.
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();

    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    a.remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks - looks like promising. Works fine on my machine locally - I'll have to test it on the test server to verify.